# Building up an RDD with a recursive Union in Scala within Spark

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, apache-spark, rdd

So I am fairly new to functional programming and Spark and Scala so forgive me if this is obvious... But basically I have a list of files through out HDFS that meet certain criteria, ie something like this:

```
    val List = (
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=01/000140_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=03/000258_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=05/000270_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=01/000297_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=30/000300_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=01/000362_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=29/000365_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=01/000397_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=15/000436_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=16/000447_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=01/000529_0",
"hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/partday=17/000585_0" )
```

I now need to build up an RDD to work with from this list... My thought was to use a recursive Union... Basically a function something like:

```
def dostuff(line: String): (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]) = {
      val x = sc.textFile(line)
      val x:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = sc.textFile(x) ++ sc.textFile(line)
}
```

Then simply apply it through a map:

```
val RDD_list = List.map(l => l.dostuff)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read all the files into a single RDD like this:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(...)
sc.textFile("hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/*/*")
  .map(line => ...)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!  Should have thought of that... Follow up question though... So I have something like this now:

Comment: What do you do if the list has arbitrary filenames, and there's no reasonable equivalent of your "hdfs:///hive/some.db/BigAssHiveTable/partyear=2014/partmonth=06/*/*" pattern?